# modifying the value of DataTable attributes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I have a `DataTable` which have field for (RegisteredDate) Date and Status. 
In `RegisteredDate` field, I want to show the format of date as 'YYYY-MM-DD' and in status field Active (1) or Closed (0).

In database, the sample values of `RegisteredDate` and `Status` are ::

```
   RegisteredDate                   Status
2020-01-03 13:32:11.370                1
2020-01-12 11:23:48.330                1
2020-01-12 11:23:49.923                1
```

But in DataTable I am getting the values as `/Date(1578823190740)/`. Please see the attached image.

Also, when the DataTable loads it should be in descending order of Id. How can I do this?

```
/// datatable code 
var Popup, dataTable;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("testing...");
        dataTable = $("#tbl_vehicle").DataTable({

            "ajax":{
                "url": "/Vehicles/GetVehicle",
                "type": "GET", 
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "VehicleType" },
                { "data": "Amount" },
                { "data": "RenewPeriod" },
                { "data": "RegisteredDate" },
                { "data": "RegisteredBy" },
                { "data": "Status" },
                { "data": "ModifiedBy" },
                { "data": "ModifiedDate" }
            ],
            "language": {
                "emptyTable" : "No data available, please click on <b>Add</b> button"
            }

        });

    });
```

controller code for loading data

```
/// controller code
public ActionResult GetVehicle()
{
    List<Vehicle> vehicleList = db.Vehicle.ToList<Vehicle>();
    return Json(new { data = vehicleList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To Display the date time in your required format you can use `moment.js` , and to use that in data table you can use `render` function of data table . First of all you have to import `momentjs` using cdn as below.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

And after importing `momentjs` change your code as below. Here I have used render function to return the content that we want to display in particular format

```js
var Popup, dataTable;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("testing...");
        dataTable = $("#tbl_vehicle").DataTable({

            "ajax":{
                "url": "/Vehicles/GetVehicle",
                "type": "GET", 
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "VehicleType" },
                { "data": "Amount" },
                { "data": "RenewPeriod" },
                { 
                  "data": "RegisteredDate",
                  "render": function(data){
                    var date = moment(data).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
                    return date;
                  }
                },
                { "data": "RegisteredBy" },
                { 
                  "data": "Status",
                   "render" : function(data){
                      if(data === "true") return "1"
                      else return "0"
                   }
                },
                { "data": "ModifiedBy" },
                { 
                  "data": "ModifiedDate",
                  "render": function(data){
                    var date = moment(data).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
                    return date;
                  }
                }
            ],
            "language": {
                "emptyTable" : "No data available, please click on <b>Add</b> button"
            }

        });

    });
```

Comment: What about loading the data in Descending Order of Id?

Comment: To do the same you have to modify your controller code as below
 List<Vehicle> vehicleList = db.Vehicle.ToList<Vehicle>().OrderbyDescending(x=>x.Id);

Answer (score 1):

You can simply convert the date into your desired format in the controller itself.
For this you have to add a string property `RegisteredDateString` in the Model class and bind this property in datatable instead of `RegisteredDate`.

```
 List<Vehicle> vehicleList = db.Vehicle.ToList<Vehicle>();
 vehicleList.ForEach(x => x.RegisteredDateString = 
 x.RegisteredDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```